# vuejs doesn't load images in the path like /somepage/id

Tags: vue.js

In my app i have several routes like:

- /
- /login
- /event/id

On login page i have the image that loads well -

```
<img src="img/test.jpg">
```

all my images are in public/img folder.

**On Event/id** page i have the image that isn't loaded - 
In devtools i get a strange url for this image : http://localhost:8080/event/img/event-img.jpg
but the correct path should be http://localhost:8080/img/event-img.jpg.

**I don't know why but vuejs adds /event/ string in the path**.  But for Login page VueJs doesn't do that.

Please give an advice.

Comment: Just use the root URL then, i.e. : `<img src="/img/test.jpg" />`

Comment: @Terry and maybe you also know why i can't reach the url like http://localhost:8081/event/10 directly, not using router-link but manually?

Comment: I would consider your other question a standalone one that should be asked separately, since it is distinct from your current question and has to deal with vue-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment, you simply need to use the root URL, i.e. starting with a `/` character. So, your `src` attribute should be updated as such:

```
<img src="/img/test.jpg" />
```

The reason why this works is because when you're building your Vue CLI app, everything in the public folder is accessible via the root URL. Therefore, a URL relative to the root, instead of to the current page URL, is needed.